# .exe Program Run Automation in Windows 2012

Tags: service, scheduled-tasks, exe, windows-server-2012, autorun

I have  a Exe program which run fines and update the log when I run it manually or create a batch script run the .bat file (By double click/call from CMD prompt).

When I am trying to automate this process by creating scheduled task/ creating a service it don't work.

In Windows 2012 Srvany.exe also dont work so i am not able to create a service , even though I create a service using SC Create command the service  fails to run in windows 2012.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer- This was happening as My Program was not running at Interactive mode,As per Microsoft a task runs at Interactive mode when "Run when User logged on" option is chosen, if we choose other option the program will not run at interactive mode.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx